# Launch web scraper with Windows task manager "Whether user is logged on or not"

Tags: node.js, windows, puppeteer, taskmanager

I have a bit of an issue running my nodejs / puppeteer scraper. When I try running the main script through Windows task manager (on Windows Server 2022 Standard) "Only when the user is logged on", it works fine, but when I select "Whether user is logged on or not" it does not (does not start a cmd as it should) and throws an error (0x1). Does anyone know why ? Ty all :)

I tried executing the script with a .bat, which works on its own, so I configured my task to run the .bat file instead, but it throws out the same error.

Comment: Please share a [mcve]. Thanks.